# Error in application validation,ERROR_B2B_API_RETURNED_ERROR in phone pe flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile-development, phonepe

I've implemeted phone pe SDK successfully with test credentials given on https://developer.phonepe.com/v1/docs/uat-testing/

But whene we tested it on production mode it gives error below,

```
I/phonepe_payment_sdk( 7853): onActivityResult: requestCode:725 resultCode:0, data: key_error_code:ERROR_B2B_API_RETURNED_ERROR
I/phonepe_payment_sdk( 7853): key_error_result:{"success":false,"code":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR","message":"There is an error trying to process your transaction at the moment. Please try again in a while. [message = Error in application validation]","data":{}}
```

Anyone knows about this error, salt key & other params also change by production.
There are no error documentation found on phone pe.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details? Like the format in which you are giving the params. From the looks of it looks like the maybe the params are given in incorrect format.

Also the debug-Build that you run while developing the app and the release-Build
have different package signature (this also changes while publishing on play store as google signs the package, so you should probably request appID for this package signature if you are planning to publish on the play store). Make sure you are calling the init function with the correct appID(for that corresponding package signature)

Comment: I’ve setup everything like documentation given & also testing from YouTube video.I’ve called Paytm sdk support they said you have to submit first live application play store link after they verified it then live transactions are started.Thankyou.